# error processing a workflow SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I did a workflow with visual studio workflow foundation 
when I run the workflow from sharepoint gives me this error ... does anyone know how to repair the damage ?

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range. 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.Hex(Char ch) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentTypeId..ctor(String id) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWinOETaskService.CreateTaskWithContentType(Guid taskId, SPWorkflowTaskProperties properties, String taskContentTypeId, HybridDictionary specialPermissions)     --- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) 
    at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) 
    at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) 
    at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams) 
    at System.Workflow.Activities.CallExternalMethodActivity.Execute(ActivityExecutionContext executionContext) 
    at System.Workflow.ComponentModel.ActivityExecutor`1.Execute(T activity, ActivityExecutionContext executionContext) 
    at System.Workflow.ComponentModel.ActivityExecutorOperation.Run(IWorkflowCoreRuntime workflowCoreRuntime) 
    at System.Workflow.Runtime.Scheduler.Run()

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your source code its hard to know for sure what caused the issue, but it looks like you tried to make an unsafe update without using the [AllowUnsafeUpdates()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.allowunsafeupdates.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) function.  Updating the Author field on a list item would require this, for example but there are a number of reasons you might need it.

> System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)